# What is the best practice to intercept an exception handler in Linux kernel

Tags: c, exception, linux-kernel, intercept

I need to intercept the exception handling of page fault in Linux kernel, but I'm not allowed to modify the kernel source and compile the kernel. I have to do this in a kernel module. I now have several approach.

---

1. copy the IDT table and replace the ISR of page fault. However, I looked into the assembly code of the kernel and found that the ISR calls some functions whose address cannot be determined at the compile time of the module. For example, `callq  *0x2b0a07(%rip)        # ffffffff81620100 <pv_irq_ops+0x30>`.
2. use kprobe/jprobe mechanism to intercept `do_page_fault`, but not all kernel are configured with kprobe enabled.
3. replace the first several bytes of `do_page_fault` with a jump instruction which jumps to my code. However, I need to use `do_page_fault` latter in my code. I have to put the replaced instructions to another place, but the size of x86 code is hard to determin, and if one of the replaced instructions is jump, things will get more complicated.

Do you guys have any idea to solve the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Change the IDT entry to point to your handler. Call the original handler from there if/when needed. No need to copy the IDT or patch the existing code.

Comment: Your answer inspired me. There is a little problem of this approach: the trap frame and error code has to be pushed and poped twice. This will downgrade the performance a little. If there is no other elegant approach, this one should be my choice.

Comment: I'd not want to use exceptions for anything but exceptional situations. They aren't cheap even when you have to go through the trap code just once.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Do you have by a chance reference to code that do this?